# Is it possible to achieve session scope behavior in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, session, reactive

Currently experimenting with reactive programming using Spring WebFlux. 
I need to reset some values(create new instance of one class) every session.

It is not possible to inject a @RequestScope or @SessionScope bean as it will end up with IllegalStateExcepion error.

Is it possible to achieve session scope behavior in Spring Webflux? Any tips what can I use to achieve that?

Comment: The current `@RequestScope` and `@SessionScope` are only usable in the classic Spring MVC paradigm. You would probably need a custom scope to support this in a reactive way.

Comment: Yes but how to achieve that? Is there any way to reset several values whenever session starts. For example: I have starting ID of element that will be returned from DB and then this ID will be changed to ID of another element which will be returned next. So every time new session is starting this ID needs to be reset to default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by using hazelcast session replication.

Answer (score 1):

## Spring Session

In order to use sessions in Spring Webflux, you can use [Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5), more specifically you can use the [integration with Spring Webflux's WebSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#websession-how)

Some tutorial can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session-reactive